# How to inflate View inside of ViewHolder for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to inflate a view inside of the ViewHolder for RecyclerView, but it doesn't work. 
I would appreciate if someone give me an advice on the following sample code.

```
class MyProfileViewHolder(
    itemView: View,
    private val myProfileViewModel: MyProfileViewModel) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

private val userImageView: ImageView = itemView.myProfileMainUserImageView
private val myProfileSelfIntroductionText: TextView = itemView.myProfileSelfIntroductionText
private val favoriteEmptyFrame: FrameLayout = itemView.favoriteEmptyFrame

fun bind() {
    // DefaultImage
    val url = myProfileViewModel.user.getProfileImageUrl(myProfileViewModel.selectedImageIndex, "medium")
    profileViewHelper.setProfileMainImage(
            userImageView,
            myProfileViewModel.user.getProfileImageUrl(myProfileViewModel.selectedImageIndex, "medium"),
            myProfileViewModel.user.gender
    )
    // Self introduction
    myProfileSelfIntroductionText.text = myProfileViewModel.user.description

    // favorite empty frame
    when(myProfileViewModel.emptyViewType) {
        MyProfileViewModel.EMPTY_VIEW_TYPE_FAVORITE -> {
            // it doesn't work
            LayoutInflater.from(itemView.context).inflate(R.layout.section_favorite_empty, favoriteEmptyFrame, false)
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the sample code I'm trying to on Cacher including the other file such as Adapter and xml.
https://snippets.cacher.io/snippet/e02fb192f90c21765e7e

Answer (score 0):

I could not found a way of doing it, there is a requirement of having a inflated layout before the creation of the viewHolder.

But you can workaround this restriction with this code:

```
class MyProfileViewHolder(
    itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

...

MyProfileViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.m_layout, container, false))
```